# Why is the listing $\{3\} , \{2\} , \{2,3\} , \{1\}, \{1,2\} , \{1,3\} , \{1,2,3\}$ considered a total order?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Let $S = \{\{1,2,3\}, \{1\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{2,3\}\}$.
>
> Find a topological sorting for $\subseteq$ on $S$.

We can use the theorem that goes "A finite, nonempty poset must have a minimal element" to find the topsort for $\subseteq$ on $S$.

According to the definition of topsort,  $\{3\}, \{2\}, \{2,3\}, \{1\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{1,2,3\}$ is a topsort since if $a \subseteq b$, $a$ precedes $b$ for all $a$ and $b$ in $S$. Apparently, this topsort is a total order.

According to the definition of total order - $\le$ is a total order iff $a \le b$ or $b \le a$ for all $a$ and $b$ in $S$.

$\{3\}, \{2\}, \{2,3\}, \{1\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{1,2,3\}$ doesn't look like a total order to me. For example, $\operatorname{not}(\{3\}\le \{2\})$.

Please, elaborate.

Thanks.

edit:

The definition of topological sorting from my textbook:

"Let (order relation symbol 1) be a partial order on S. Let (order relation symbol 2) be a total order on S. (order relation symbol 2) is a topological sort for (order relation symbol 1) iff for all a, b in S if a (order relation symbol 1) b, then a (order relation symbol 2) b. "

Comment: It would be useful if you could quote the precise definition of topsort you are using. I suspect it implies that the total ordering is defined by the sorted order, which is different from inclusion of sets.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that the **order** is very important (hence the term *listing*), and what is meant is that the relation $$
\newcommand{\set}[1]{{\{ #1 \}}}
\set{3} \leq
\set{2} \leq
\set{2,3} \leq
\set{1} \leq
\set{1,2} \leq
\set{1,3} \leq
\set{1,2,3}
$$ is a topological sorting for $\subseteq$ on $S$.

Comment: This chain of inequalities is correct if one looks at the hasse graph of the topsort. So, do we conclude the topsort is a total order as determined by the graph of it? Because, now we can apply the definition of total order to the chain of inequalities above.

Comment: @David12345: There is generally no _the_ topsort: a partial order may have several different topsorts.  Another one for $\subseteq$ on $S$ would be $$\{1\}\leq\{2\}\leq\{3\}\leq\{1,2\}\leq\{1,3\}\leq\{2,3\}\leq\{1,2,3\}.$$  All that matters is that whenever we have $A \subseteq B$ we also have $A \leq B$ (and the $\leq$ order is total).

Answer (score 1):

Writing a (finite) set as a sequence $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ is essentially the same defining an order relation $\le $ on the set $\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ by declaring $a_i\le a_j$ iff $i\le j$. This is a total order because the usual order on the index set $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ is total.
The key point in this example is of course that the sequence is such that $a_i\subseteq a_j$ implies $i\le j$ (but not necessarily the other way around).

Answer (score 0):

You're right. I don't see a total order either. Actually, S is the powerset of {1,2,3} without the empty set, $S=\mathcal{P}(\{1,2,3\})\setminus \emptyset$. And powersets make partial orders by inclusion.

Also, the topsort you wrote is not a total order, because the two first elements of the list are not related, as you noticed yourself. $\{3\} \nleq \{2\}$ and $\{2\} \nleq \{3\}$.

Comment: But the definition of topsort explicitly says that topsort is a total order.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The definition says that $a \subseteq b ~\Rightarrow~ a ~\text{precedes}~ b$. This means that if $\subseteq$ is a partial order, then the topsort is a partial order, too.

Comment: "Let (order relation symbol 1) be a partial order on S.

Let (order relation symbol 2) be a total order on S.

(order relation symbol 2) is a topological sort for (order relation symbol 1) iff for all a, b in S if a (order relation symbol 1) b, then a (order relation symbol 2) b. " Now I am confused.

Comment: Yes, substitute (order symbol 1) with $\subseteq$ and (order symbol 2) with "precedes". The definition tells you that you can produce a total order from the topsort of a partial order. But this doesn't go the other way round: if you manage to produce a topsort from an order, this doesn't mean that the initial order is total.

Comment: My textbook says "the topsort gives a total order that has the required property: a ⊆ b if a precedes b". Am I understanding it wrong?